# openGl GPU optimization when rendering stacks of primitives

Tags: opengl, gpu

If I render 15 fully opaque quads with the same size on top of each other, depth test disabled, is the GPU hardware /software cleaver enough just to process the topmost quad and discard the other vertices/fragments? Or would one benefit from using the stencil buffer to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, it will generate fragments for all of the opaque quads. Also, if you disable the depth test, you may see the back surface on the screen. Because the depth testing is disable and whoever is rendered last will draw the screen.

Even, if you use the stencil buffer the fragments are still generated for the quads, pass through stencil and depth tests.

Answer (score 3):

Most GPUs will overdraw in this scenario which will be very bad for performance if your quads are large. Rather than use the stencil buffer, the best way to optimise is probably to enable depth testing, assign appropriate depth values and render your quads front to back.

However, under certain conditions (e.g. no blending) tile based deferred rendering (TBDR) GPUs common in many mobile devices (particularly PowerVR devices used by all iOS devices and many Android devices) will do a process known as hidden surface removal (HSR) which will optimize this case and avoid rendering the pixels that will be obscured.

Comment: Even if you render the quads front to back, the vertices of the back quads are processed and fragments will be generated. They are just discarding them instead of drawing.

Comment: And don't change the depth-test direction mid-frame. That will break hierarchical z-buffering optimization on most GPUs, which results in early z-testing being done per-fragment instead of more coarse z-cull (entire primitive might be culled with a single test).

Comment: @mmostajab: Not on TBDR hardware. Mobile GPUs work differently (for opaque geometry).